# Need to have url like /stories/<id>/episodes/1

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I create a new episode, id automatically increments. What I need? Imagine, I have 10 episodes for a different stories, so if I create an episode for story(for example, with id=5), it will assign id for new episode as 11. Url will be like /stories/5/episodes/11, but I need something like /stories/5/episodes/1. It would be good to store episodes id according to story, not all number episodes from all stories. How to do that?

```py
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Then you will need to add a `rank` field to the `Episode` that keeps track of the episode for that story.

Comment: You are mixing concepts: surrogate keys and natural keys. django works with surrogate keys, if you need additional info, like story number or episode number inside story, just add them.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you provide a code? Will the new episode be stored in database with id = 1 for a new story?

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov: no, that is completely impossible, since a primary key is *unique* so there can not exists two `Episode`s simultaneously with the same primary key.

Comment: Just as Willem said, add a new field to your `Episode` model, e.g. `number`, that records which episode this is for **a particular story**. Then in your view, the number you get from the URL isn't the episode id, but the episode number, so you have to fetch it from within the set of episodes belonging to your story:  `story.episode_set.get(number=number)`. The episode number is **unrelated** to the episode id, which is just the primary key.

Comment: You can add number field in model and auto increment the number field in views.py while saving the detail of episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a field for episode number in Episode model.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    episode_number = models.IntegerField(null=True) # added field
```

In **views.py**, add a function to save episode number.

```
def get_episode_number(instance):
    episode = Episode.objects.filter(story=instance).order_by('-episode_number')
    if not episode:
        return 1
    else:
        return episode[0].episode_number + 1
```

call the function when saving the data like if you are using ModelForm:

```
if form.is_valid():
        form_save = form.save(commit=False)
        form_save.episode_number = get_episode_number(story) # pass your story instance here
        form_save.save()
```

This will increment episode number for every story you save.